# Question about Visual Studio Code linefeed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can I get auto linefeed here?
Thank you very much.

[image]

i am a new learner of python.

i do not  know if it is proper ask this kind of question here.

Answer (score 0):

An existing [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167264), which **can only be wrapped with the mouse** at present.

You can follow up [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139717) on github to obtain real-time consultation.